# Tips for buying laptop

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I am confused which laptop should I buy. I am an above beginner in blender. Can you suggest which is the best laptop for blender around $1100.

Comment: [what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/9596)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer hardware and not about using Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need the portability, I wouldn't bother with a laptop. Their CPUs/GPUs are optimized for battery consumption, not performance.

BUT!

If you only want to use it for modelling, buy ample amounts of RAM (8GB+), a decent CPU with good single-thread performance (most modelling, I think, is single-threaded), and then throw the rest of your money at the GPU (OpenGL3.3+ compliant, of course).

If you're going to do heavy sculpting, go for 16-32MB RAM.

Comment: is 8gb ram enough for blender

Comment: It is enough _for modeling_, at least. Of course, more is better.

Comment: Is it enough for intermediators.

Comment: You mean intermediate level modelers? If so, it would probably not be enough. I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: 8 GB or RAM is enough for pretty much all modelling needs of any level. Situations where one would need to have more detail than you can fit in 8GB visible for modelling tasks are rare. I have modeled stuff even having heavy photogrammetry reconstructions as reference with 8 GB of RAM without problems that would prevent me from working. Obviously with more RAM it is simply more convenient, faster - you can have more stuff open, don't need to worry about closing stuff that you are not working on at that moment. Unless of course you work with fur, hair or particles - buy a desktop then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use blender 2.8, make sure that the video card (GPU) have OpenGL 3.3 or higher.

Comment: OpenGL 3.3 release date was March 11, 2010. I think your advice is valid: it's always a good idea not to buy a laptop with a graphics card older than 9 years, however it does not seem to me to be very relevant. Pretty much all of them support OpenGL 3.3 or higher these days especially the ones one would be looking at for work with 3d.